# elasticsearch - unique dates from datetime

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following data in elasticsearch

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "employees", "_id" : "1" } }
{"id":1,"name":"Huntlee Dargavel","pub_date" : "2015-01-01T00:03:50+0000"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "employees", "_id" : "2" } }
{"id":2,"name":"Othilia Cathel","pub_date" : "2015-01-01T00:08:50+0000"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "employees", "_id" : "3" } }
{"id":3,"name":"Winston Waren","pub_date" : "2015-01-01T09:10:50+0000"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "employees", "_id" : "4" } }
{"id" : 4,"name" : "Alan Thomas","pub_date" : "2015-01-02T00:03:50+0000"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "employees", "_id" : "5" } }
{"id":5,"name":"Huntlee Dargavel","pub_date" : "2015-01-02T05:03:50+0000"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "employees", "_id" : "6" } }
{"id":6,"name":"Othilia Cathel","pub_date" : "2015-01-03T00:03:50+0000"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "employees", "_id" : "7" } }
{"id":7,"name":"Winston Waren","pub_date" : "2015-01-04T00:03:50+0000"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "employees", "_id" : "8" } }
{"id" : 8,"name" : "Alan Thomas","pub_date" : "2015-01-01T00:07:50+0000"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "employees", "_id" : "9" } }
{"id" : 9,"name" : "Alan Thomas","pub_date" : "2015-01-04T00:03:50+0000"}
```

Now when I try to get the unique dates from the data, using the following query:

```
GET /employees/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "UNIQ_DATES": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pub_date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following is the output:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "genres" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1420329830000,
          "key_as_string" : "2015-01-04T00:03:50.000Z",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : 1420070630000,
          "key_as_string" : "2015-01-01T00:03:50.000Z",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 1420070870000,
          "key_as_string" : "2015-01-01T00:07:50.000Z",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 1420070930000,
          "key_as_string" : "2015-01-01T00:08:50.000Z",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 1420103450000,
          "key_as_string" : "2015-01-01T09:10:50.000Z",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 1420157030000,
          "key_as_string" : "2015-01-02T00:03:50.000Z",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 1420175030000,
          "key_as_string" : "2015-01-02T05:03:50.000Z",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 1420243430000,
          "key_as_string" : "2015-01-03T00:03:50.000Z",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the `unique datetime` instead of `unique dates`. Is it possible to get the unique dates from the datetime data in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Date-Histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html)** for this.

```
GET employees/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "UNIQ_DATES": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "pub_date",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      }
    }
  }
}
```